# Resize gstremer video in gtkmm

Tags: gstreamer, gtkmm

I got a sample video application in gtk using gstreamer from their official site (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/toolkit-integration.html?gi-language=c). When I maximize the window, video didn't get resized. When I tried the same using d3dvideosink, video get resized but it was transparent.Attached screenshot for both. Any suggestion is really appreciated.

When maximize application obtained from gstremer site
[image]

When using d3dvideosink video get transparent
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I resolved issue by upgrading gstreamer plugin in GTK and use configure event
Use **d3d11videosink** for video streaming which allow "gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle" api in the latest release(1.20.0). d3dvideosink has transparency issue so do not use that.
Add a  configure event for video window(Gtk::DrawingArea).
video_window->signal_configure_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(this, &example::example_function),false);
In configure event do the following

```
video_window(GdkEventConfigure *event) {   gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(video_sink), 0, 0, event->width, event->height);
    }
```

where "video_sink" is the GST_TYPE_VIDEO_OVERLAY for pipeline. Please ensure it is not null (need to null initial), else it leads to application crash.

This is for windows application.Please check [this link](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/-/merge_requests/2450/diffs?commit_id=a096207f8531742bbe7c83771524fdbf596bcec1#7d06a03be404acd9e984addcd30f4ca617a3f9d4) for more details

Comment: You can accept your own answer if it solved your issue! It would help other users!